# Trouble rendering a template with knockout.js in IE9

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-9

I'm using knockout on a relatively simple portfolio site, and while it's working like a charm in Chrome/Firefox/etc, it's not working correctly in IE (or rather, I've checked it in IE9 and it's not working there). Something appears to be going wrong in the template rendering, but IE isn't throwing any errors, and I'm having a tough time finding the error. Here's the site in question:

http://ellenflaherty.com/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just giving the site link does not help. Post the code relavant to the loading and rendering of these templates that you speak of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that IE9 does not like your attempt to load the template into a script tag using `$.load`. You may have to consider an alternative, like loading the template and appending the entire script tag.

Something similar to this:

```
$.get("mytmpl.html", function(tmpl) {
     $("body").append("<script id='test' type='text/html'>" + tmpl + "</" + "script>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, RP! Honestly, I had no idea where the code was problematic, so it was really helpful to get pointed in the right direction. The method you suggested wasn't working, so I ended up doing a php include for IE, which seemed to take care of it.

Comment: OK- glad that it is working for you.  I had tested the above method and it was working for me, but obviously not in your project.  No big deal, sounds like you found a suitable solution.